# Apache Zeppelin - Can't load a dataframe from a HIVE table using SparkR

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, sparkr

I need to load a dataframe from a Hive table and for that I followed this instruction from Apache Spark 2.3 docs.(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html). I'm doing that by a Zeppelin notebook.

Can someone please explain how to create a dataframe using SparkR? Or what I'm doing wrong? Any answer is appreciated.

#### Documentation

Queries can be expressed in HiveQL.
`results <- sql("FROM src SELECT key, value")`

#### My code:

`sp_df <- sql("SELECT * FROM sparkr_test")`

#### Results of my code:

`head(sp_df)`
`[1] “SELECT * FROM sparkr_test”`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your data located, and have you registered the source data as a table? You need to run something like:

```
sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sparkr_test (column1 INT, column2 STRING ...) USING hive")
sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'path/to/data/data.txt' INTO TABLE sparkr_test")
```

before you can query the table

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it by specifying the library.

`SparkR::sql("select * from mytable")`